# What is calibrating a sensor panel and how to calibrate a sensor panel using arduino

Tags: arduino

I am using a Polalu sensor panel and I found out that sensor panel needed to be calibrated first. I found the following code but I am not getting the concept clearly and I am trying to do this using arduino.

```
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SENSORS; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(qtrrc.calibratedMinimumOn[i]);
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  Serial.println();

  // print the calibration maximum values measured when emitters were on
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_SENSORS; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(qtrrc.calibratedMaximumOn[i]);
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
```

Comment: I am new to arduino and also for the polalu sensor panels. please help me

Comment: is it detecting white or black?